# how do i track events in firebase analytics in ionic v1

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-analytics, ionic-v1

I have successfully installed cordova-plugin-firebase plugin in my ionic v1 application.

https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

I am trying to figure out how to analyze specific events triggered in my ionic v1 app.

For example, I tried this below but I dont see any of these info in the Firebase Dashboard of the app:

```
  window.FirebasePlugin.logEvent("select_content", {content_type: "page_view", item_id: "home"});
  window.FirebasePlugin.setScreenName("Advertisement 1");
```

Here are the screenshots of the analytics tracking. Nothing showing on the specific events:

[image]
[image]

Question is how do I track specific events using Firebase Analytics on ionic v1 using cordova-plugin-firebase plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

I do it the same way. You just have to wait a minute or a little bit longer to see the events.